# Пояснить list.index()

Tags: python

Всем привет! Поясни, пожалуйста в деталях смысл метода index() в списке. Не просто примером, а с пояснением. Есть код который работает но понять как работает метод index() в данном коде не доходит...

```
            test=[
                    {'is_blocked': 0, 'ip': '10.10.10.1', 'id': 113},
                    {'is_blocked': 0, 'ip': '10.10.10.16', 'id': 113},
                    {'is_blocked': 0, 'ip': '10.10.10.1', 'id': 114},
                    {'is_blocked': 0, 'ip': '10.10.10.16', 'id': 115},
                    {'is_blocked': 0, 'ip': '10.10.10.1', 'id': 114},
                    {'is_blocked': 0, 'ip': '10.10.10.16', 'id': 116}
            ]
            def f(arr):
                    vals, ips, res=[], [], []
                    for i in arr:
                        ip= i['ip']
                        del i['ip']
                        try:
                            ips[vals.index(i)]+= ","+ip
                        except:
                            vals.append(i)
                            ips.append(ip)
                    for i in range(len(vals)):
                        vals[i]['ip']=ips[i]
                        res.append(vals[i])
                    print res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index - показывает (ВНИМАНИЕ!) индекс, то есть номер запрашиваемого элемента в списке, нумерация начинается с нуля.

```
>>> list = ['zero','one','two']
>>> list.index('zero')
0
>>> list.index('one')
1
>>> list.index('two')
2
```

**UPD**

```
ips[vals.index(i)]+= ","+ip
vals.index(i) // вызывает ошибку если элемента нету в списке
//и срабатывает код
except:
   vals.append(i)
   ips.append(ip)
// в противном случае берется ip и добавляется к элементу который находится под этим индексом
```